# Jenkins sending same emails all build statuses

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I managed to clone GIT hub repo in Jenkins and now trying to build the fetched maven projects in Jenkins. I have 7 projects fetched from GITHUB and they are dependent on each other, i.e. some of the projects have dependencies defined for other projects in their POM.
I have one job defined with root level pom.xml specifying all child projects to be built as multi-module . All goes well and jenkins builds child project and parent project well. However, irrespective of child projects build status i.e. build success OR build failed ..jenkins always send 
email with **"Jenkins build is back to normal"** as soon as parent project finishes build and triggers child project's build -which doesn't make sense at all. I have configured child level project i.e. modules for email notification but that gets overridden by my parent project's email settings and always the same email is triggered. Anyone had same problem before?

Comment: By digging more in I found following in Jenkins logs

Comment: hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel Channel to Maven /var/lib/jenkins/tools/JDK/JDK_6u33/bin/java,-cp, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-agent-1.2.jar:/var/lib/jenkins/tools/Maven/Maven-2.2.1/boot/classworlds-1.1.jar, hudson.maven.agent.Main, /var/lib/jenkins/tools/Maven/Maven-2.2.1, /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-2.16.jar, /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven-interceptor-1.2.jar,/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven2.1-interceptor-1.2.jar]

Comment: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel

Comment: Did anyone experience same issue?

Comment: A few years later, I'm seeing this on Jenkins ver. 1.590.  Any job that fails twice in a row and also has passing subproject builds, gets the "build is back to normal" email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [email-ext plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Email-ext+plugin) . Though this is not a direct solution to your problem, but this plugin is much better than the default one ; it will also give you diagnostic capabilities when you use `Pre-send Script` option here you can set/unset or print a variable to see whether control is reaching the right place.